# Как зациклить функцию и вернуть нужные значения?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция, нужно чтоб при определенном введеном аргументе просчитывалось значение и функции, затем просчитать значение функции с предыдущим аргументом и так до тех пор пока оно не станет равно 1 и после этого все значения добавить в массив.

```
def f(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n / 2
    else:
        return 3 * n + 1
```

Например при значении 13 будет последовательность:
13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1

Comment: Про рекурсию читали? Почитайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно вызывать функцию пока число не станет меньше, либо равным единице.
Это можно легко реализовать через рекурсию.

```
def f(n, numbers_list=[]):
    # Проверяем меньше либо равно число единице
    # Если да, то возвращаем список, в который мы добавили числа
    if n <= 1:
        return numbers_list

    # Если число четное, то добавляем его в список - делим на два, и вызываем фун-цию
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        numbers_list.append(n)
        f(n / 2)

    # Если число не четное, добавляем его в список, и вызываем фун-цию
    else:
        numbers_list.append(n)
        f(3 * n + 1)
    
    # Возвращаем весь, список
    return numbers_list
```

Answer (score 1):

зациклить функцию и потом вернуть массив можно так:

```
def f(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
    else:
        return 3 * n + 1
    
number = 13
res = [number]
while number!=1:
    number = f(number)
    res.append(number)
print(res)  # [13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

или, как уже было сказано, использовать вместо цикла рекурсию:

```
def f(n):
    return [n] if n==1 else [n] + f(n//2 if n%2==0 else 3*n+1)

f(13)  # [13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(n):
    while n>1 :
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n=n/2
        else:
            n=3 * n + 1
    print(n)

f(13)
```

Comment: В таком виде функция ничего полезного не делает. `print` не на месте.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]